# PySNMP Error InterfaceIndexOrZero Error

Tags: python, counter, snmp, mib, pysnmp

I am trying to get IPSLA data out of a Cisco router. While trying to use the most basic examples that I have come across online including the official documents from PySnmp. The error seems to be related to receiving negative or zero value objects from a query. I haven't been able to find ANY help on this, using their suggested fix hasn't helped.

When trying to execute a snmp query via PySnmp I am getting this error:

```
[billiam@nunya]$ python snmptests.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snmptests.py", line 33, in <module>
    cmdgen.MibVariable('CISCO-RTTMON-MIB', '1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.42.1.2.10.1.1')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/oneliner/cmdgen.py", line 424, in getCmd
    kwargs.get('contextName', null)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/oneliner/cmdgen.py", line 277, in getCmd
    self.makeReadVarBinds(varNames),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/oneliner/cmdgen.py", line 201, in makeReadVarBinds
    [ (x, self._null) for x in varNames ], oidOnly=True
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/oneliner/cmdgen.py", line 209, in makeVarBinds
    varName.resolveWithMib(self.mibViewController, oidOnly=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/oneliner/mibvar.py", line 159, in resolveWithMib
    self.__modName, self.__symName
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/builder.py", line 299, in importSymbols
    self.loadModules(modName, **userCtx)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/builder.py", line 259, in loadModules
    'MIB module \"%s\" load error: %s' % (modPath, traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info()))
pysnmp.smi.error.SmiError: MIB module "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs/CISCO-RTTMON-MIB.py" load error: ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/builder.py", line 255, in loadModules\n    exec(modData, g)\n', '  File "<string>", line 246, in <module>\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyasn1/type/univ.py", line 107, in clone\n    return self.__class__(value, tagSet, subtypeSpec, namedValues)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyasn1/type/univ.py", line 22, in __init__\n    self, value, tagSet, subtypeSpec\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyasn1/type/base.py", line 69, in __init__\n    self._verifySubtypeSpec(value)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyasn1/type/base.py", line 33, in _verifySubtypeSpec\n    raise c(\'%s at %s\' % (i, self.__class__.__name__))\n', 'ValueConstraintError: ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(), ValueRangeConstraint(-2147483648, 2147483647)), ValueRangeConstraint(0, 2147483647)) failed at: "ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(), ValueRangeConstraint(-2147483648, 2147483647)) failed at: "ValueRangeConstraint(-2147483648, 2147483647) failed at: "140504945132592""" at InterfaceIndexOrZero\n']
```

**snmptests.py**

I have tried to use their listed "[fix](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/faq.html#1a)" for this error.

```
from pysnmp.proto import rfc1155, rfc1902, api
from pyasn1.codec.ber import encoder, decoder
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
from pysnmp.smi import builder
# --- hack Counter type

def counterCloneHack(self, *args):
    if args and args[0] < 0:
        args = (0xffffffff+args[0]-1,) + args[1:]

    return self.__class__(*args)

rfc1155.Counter.clone = counterCloneHack
rfc1902.Counter32.clone = counterCloneHack

cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

mibBuilder = cmdGen.snmpEngine.msgAndPduDsp.mibInstrumController.mibBuilder


mibSources = mibBuilder.getMibSources() + (
    builder.DirMibSource('/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs'),
    )

mibBuilder.setMibSources(*mibSources)

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdGen.getCmd(
    cmdgen.CommunityData('public'),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('10.8.25.65', 161)),
    cmdgen.MibVariable('CISCO-RTTMON-MIB', '1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.42.1.2.10.1.1')
)

# Check for errors and print out results
if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
else:
    if errorStatus:
        print('%s at %s' % (
            errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
            errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex)-1] or '?'
            )
        )
    else:
        for name, val in varBinds:
            print('%s = %s' % (name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))
```

Comment: I think you are getting a similar error, but not the same. That is why the "fix" doesn't work. You appear to be getting this error when you are loading the mib. Your fix page is getting the error when a bad counter is received.

Comment: My guess is that CISCO-RTTMON-MIB.py is broken in part of default value  initialization. Could you find that huge integer 140504945132592 there? Try  to just change it to some reasonable value (e.g. within mentioned constraints). On a side note: we are working on a pure-Python MIB compiler (http://sf.net/projects/pysmi/) which will generate better pysnmp MIBs. So you may consider using pysmi for further MIBs generation.

Comment: I tried using your smi converter as well and I still had issues. Different issues, but still the mib.py isn't correct.

Comment: A fellow programmer just did some fixes to pysmi. So lease try again. We are interested in fixing all issues you encounter with pysmi. Please report your problems to pysmi developers/mailing list.